# Why does PowerShell treat my HTML containing a # as a comment?

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to create HMTL formatted emails, where some messages are coloured red. I do it like this:

```bsh
[void]$mailBody.add("<p style="color:#FF0000";>Error Adding User ($Username) to Group ($group) </p> `r`n")
```

But the `#` in the HTML is commenting out the rest of the line.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You need to escape the inner quotes of your string with a backtick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same quotes inside a quoted string. That cannot work. PowerShell will parse that as `"<p style="` followed by a comment. Use different inner quotes:

```bsh
[void]$mailBody.add("<p style='color:#FF0000';>Error Adding User ($Username) to Group ($group) </p> `r`n")
```

or escape your inner quotes:

```bsh
[void]$mailBody.add("<p style=`"color:#FF0000`";>Error Adding User ($Username) to Group ($group) </p> `r`n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an uncommon thing [as this example shows](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell-12/12627/html-output-with-color-text)...

```
$Style = "<style>"
$Style = $Style + "BODY{background-color:#D7D8D8;}"
$Style = $Style + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$Style = $Style + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$Style = $Style + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$Style = $Style + "</style>"
$ServerList = Get-Content -path B:\MYSHARE\PowershellScripts\computers.txt
$serviceList =  &{$args} IISADMIN W3SVC HTTPFilter cpsvc CitrixWMIService CtxHttp CitrixXTEServer IMAService CdmService "Citrix SMA Service"

$body = $ServerList | foreach { (Get-Service -Name $serviceList -computername $_) | 
        Select-Object MachineName, Name, DisplayName, Status | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment}

<# possible values
[enum]::GetValues([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus])
Stopped
StartPending
StopPending
Running
ContinuePending
PausePending
Paused

the field tag looks like this <td>Running</td> we need it to look like this 
<td bgcolor="#00ff00">Running</td>

#>
$colorTagTable = @{Stopped = ' bgcolor="#ff0000">Stopped<';
                   Running = ' bgcolor="#00ff00">Running<'}

#get possible values look them in text sorrounded by > < and replace them with style (pun intended).
$colorTagTable.Keys | foreach { $body = $body -replace ">$_<",($colorTagTable.$_) }

ConvertTo-HTML -head $Style -body "<H2>Validation Completed</H2> $body" | 
Out-File "B:\MYSHARE\PowershellScripts\Validated.htm"
```

So, this could be seen as a duplicate of this SO accepted answer...

> [Setting HTML font color in Powershell email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087739/setting-html-font-color-in-powershell-email)

...that uses a slightly different approach, yet, which also points back to the above resource.

You'll find more examples in a [general search for your use case](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20html%20email%20using%20color%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20html%20email%20using%20color%27&sc=0-35&sk=&cvid=20616C88471D46068B74B691408368BD).